# "Attach" a new object to a ng-repeated item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a loop of `items` which need to be dynamically replaced via an API. The problem is that the outer scope seems to loose the reference to the original object when it is replaced. How can I make the outer scope notice the change in value to an item in the array?

```js
(function(ng) {
  'use strict';

  ng.module('app', [])
    .controller('ParentController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.items = [{
          name: "Foo",
          number: 0
        }, {
          name: "Bar",
          number: 1
        }, {
          name: "Baz",
          number: 1
        }];
      }
    ])
    .controller('ItemController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        // fake code, would get from API normally
        var getFromApi = function() {
          return {
            name: $scope.item.name,
            number: $scope.item.number + 1
          };
        }

        $scope.incr = function() {
          $scope.item = getFromApi();
        }
      }
    ]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ParentController">
    <p>When you click one of the below buttons</p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-controller="ItemController">
        {{item.name}} ({{item.number}})
        <button ng-click="incr()">+</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p>This should update</p>
    <p>{{items}}</p>
    <p>...but it doesn't</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to know the **key** of the item, that you are changing the properties of, and then change this item in the collection.

To declare the key you could use **`ng-repeat="(key, item) in items"`**. The key then will be available as `$scope.key` in the `ItemController`.

Next as the `ItemController` inherits `$scope` from the `ParentController`, you can access `$scope.items` in the `ItemController` directly:

**ItemController.js:**

```
$scope.incr = function() {
  $scope.items[$scope.key] = getFromApi();
}
```

**This will only be possible, if the ItemController is a Child of ParentController or inherits it's scope otherwise.**

You can see the script running like this:

```js
(function(ng) {
  'use strict';

  ng.module('app', [])
    .controller('ParentController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.items = [{
          name: "Foo",
          number: 0
        }, {
          name: "Bar",
          number: 1
        }, {
          name: "Baz",
          number: 1
        }];
      }
    ])
    .controller('ItemController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        // fake code, would get from API normally
        var getFromApi = function() {
          return {
            name: $scope.item.name,
            number: $scope.item.number + 1
          };
        }



        $scope.incr = function() {
          $scope.items[$scope.key] = getFromApi();
        }
      }
    ]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ParentController">
    <p>When you click one of the below buttons</p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(key, item) in items" ng-controller="ItemController">
        {{item.name}} ({{item.number}})
        <button ng-click="incr()">+</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p>This updates</p>
    <p>{{items}}</p>
    <p>...and it does!</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index of the items in the parent array to replace it

```js
(function(ng) {
  'use strict';

  ng.module('app', [])
    .controller('ParentController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.items = [{
          name: "Foo",
          number: 0
        }, {
          name: "Bar",
          number: 1
        }, {
          name: "Baz",
          number: 1
        }];
      }
    ])
    .controller('ItemController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        // fake code, would get from API normally
        var getFromApi = function() {
          return {
            name: $scope.item.name,
            number: $scope.item.number + 1
          };
        }

        $scope.incr = function() {
          $scope.$parent.items[$scope.$index] = getFromApi();
        }
      }
    ]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ParentController">
    <p>When you click one of the below buttons</p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-controller="ItemController">
        {{item.name}} ({{item.number}}) {{$index}}
        <button ng-click="incr()">+</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p>This should update</p>
    <p>{{items}}</p>
    <p>...but it doesn't</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might move the API call logic to the parent controller, see [the JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bhvgxn5a/) for an example, or at least replace the modified element in `$scope.items` array in parent scope.

**EDIT**: Scrap my previous statement here, the reson it is not working is because when you assign `$scope.item` in the child scope's `incr()` method, you're not modifying the `$scope.items` array. You're just changing variable assignment in the child scope.

So, before the `incr()` call the variable assignments in memory could look like:

```
$scope.items =
   item1 -> [ js obj 1 ]
   item2 -> [ js obj 2 ]
   item3 -> [ js obj 3 ]

$scope.item -> [ js obj 1 ]
```

After `incr()` call for the first item:

```
$scope.items =
   item1 -> [ js obj 1 ]       // still obj 1 here!
   item2 -> [ js obj 2 ]
   item3 -> [ js obj 3 ]

$scope.item -> [ js obj 4 ]    // but entirely new obj here!
```

Sample code:

```
  angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('ParentController', ['$scope',

  function ($scope) {
      $scope.items = [{
          name: "Foo",
          number: 0
      }, {
          name: "Bar",
          number: 1
      }, {
          name: "Baz",
          number: 1
      }];

      // fake code, would get from API normally
      var getFromApi = function (item) {
          return {
              name: item.name,
              number: item.number + 1
          };
      }

      $scope.updateItem = function (index) {
          $scope.items[index] = getFromApi($scope.items[index]);
      };
  }])
      .controller('ItemController', ['$scope',

  function ($scope) {
      $scope.incr = function (index) {
          $scope.updateItem(index);
      }
  }]);
```

Obviously, you can get away without using `$index` if you want to identify the modified item in another way. Code above is only a simplest fix for your issue. You might event keep the `getFromApi()` in the child scope and just use the `$scope.items[$index] = getFromApi()` there (thanks to scope inheritance). I just find keeping that method in parent scope a tad more clean.

Answer (score 0):

Another (hacky) option is to simply loop through the new object, assigning the variables of the old:

```
var newItem = getFromApi();
for (var key in newItem) {
  $scope.item[key] = newItem[key];
}
```

```js
(function(ng) {
  'use strict';

  ng.module('app', [])
    .controller('ParentController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.items = [{
          name: "Foo",
          number: 0
        }, {
          name: "Bar",
          number: 1
        }, {
          name: "Baz",
          number: 1
        }];
      }
    ])
    .controller('ItemController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        // fake code, would get from API normally
        var getFromApi = function() {
          return {
            name: $scope.item.name,
            number: $scope.item.number + 1
          };
        }

        $scope.incr = function() {
          var newItem = getFromApi();
          for (var key in newItem) {
            $scope.item[key] = newItem[key];
          }
        }
      }
    ]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ParentController">
    <p>When you click one of the below buttons</p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-controller="ItemController">
        {{item.name}} ({{item.number}})
        <button ng-click="incr()">+</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p>This should update</p>
    <p>{{items}}</p>
    <p>...now it does!</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And this hacky way would work because you would keep modifying the same object as the one referenced in `$scope.items` array - as I explain in my answer. Simpler just to replace the assignment in `$scope.items` directly and not use this hack.

Comment: @kamituel Agreed! But it is another option which I thought I'd throw into the ring...